# How can I order an array in a specific order, which I define?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I want to order an array in a specific order, which I define.

I've started building a function to order those arrays, but I'm stuck and I have no clue how to solve it.

My current code:

```
public function order_spells($champions) {

    foreach(array_keys($champions) as $champion){

        if(isset($champions[$champion]['Passive']) || isset($champions[$champion]['Q']) || isset($champions[$champion]['W']) || isset($champions[$champion]['E']) || isset($champions[$champion]['R'])) {

            foreach(array_keys($champions[$champion]) as $Spell_Icon) {

                if($Spell_Icon!='General'){ 
                    //echo $Spell_Icon;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

This is the current array:

[image]

And this is the expected output:

[image]

Since I'm stuck with my current code above, I will try to isolate and simplify my problem and show it to you.

So as a simple example I have an array like this:

```
$champions = [
    "A" => 1,
    "C" => 2,
    "F" => 3,
    "B" => 4,
    "G" => 5,
    "D" => 6,
    "E" => 7,
];
```

Now I want to define the order of that array, e.g. First key `F`, then `D` and so on... How can I change my above code to get it to work as I want it to ? Or how can I order this example array here?

Another twist to mention here is, that the order maybe has more elements than the array itself. E.g.

```
Order: C,D,A,B
Array: A,B,C
```

Comment: It's nice that you have the privilege to post links and images. But please post the code/output here in your question. Also show us some effort/attempt(s), how you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: From where you get this array ? How you create it ?

Comment: I've added what you guys asked the code, usually when I do that people will point out small mistakes in the code that point me towards the solution to the real problem

Comment: Maka a change in your select, from there you have the array, so just change order of columns how you want.

Comment: It is important to me to change the order when it is all put together, not when getting it from database, it would disrupt the order of subarrays

Comment: @Higeath Try something like: `$arr = array_pop($champion["Ashe"]); $champion["Ashe"] = ["E" => $arr] + $champion["Ashe"];`

Comment: @Rizer123 you could post it as the answer! thank you!

Comment: @Higeath You're welcome. Have a nice day :) (answer posted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pop off the last element of your array with [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) and put it again at the start of the array, e.g.

```
$arr = array_pop($champion["Ashe"]);
$champion["Ashe"] = ["E" => $arr] + $champion["Ashe"];
```

**EDIT:**

As from the comments you want to sort your array by a specific order, but you don't know which elements are really in the array and which aren't. So this should work for you:

So basically first you define the order which you want with an array. Then you [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the array with another array, which you fill up with empty values with [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php).

Means you will end up with this array, where the order are the keys and all have empty arrays as value, e.g.

```
Array (
    [F] => Array ( )  
    [A] => Array ( )
    [B] => Array ( )
    [G] => Array ( )    
    [C] => Array ( )
    [E] => Array ( )
    [D] => Array ( )   
)
```

Then you can use this array with [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) to order the array as you want it. And at the end you can filter the empty arrays out with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Code:

```
<?php

    $arr = [
        "A" => 1,
        "C" => 2,
        "F" => 3,
        "B" => 4,
        "G" => 5,
        "D" => 6,
        "E" => 7,
    ];


    $order = ["F", "A", "B", "G", "C", "E", "D"];
    $order = array_combine($order, array_fill(0, count($order), []));

    $arr = array_filter(array_replace($order, $arr)); 
    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [F] => 3
    [A] => 1
    [B] => 4
    [G] => 5
    [C] => 2
    [E] => 7
    [D] => 6
)
```

Comment: @Rizer123 One last thing is there anyway to target this array instead of the last one in array? Since there could be more and I'm using the code to order this array so if I have e.g. E Q W i could reorder it to Q W E

Comment: @Higeath I think then something like this should work for you: `$champion["Ashe"] = array_replace(array_flip($order), $champion["Ashe"]);`, where `$order` is the order with the order of the keys, e.g. `$order = ["Q", "W", "E"];` <- Does that do what you want?

Comment: @Rizer123 Ive added new order function in this question, so I have multiple champions with different order of Passive Q W E R so I assign numbers to temporary array let say we have W Q R , Passive is 1 Q 2 W 3 E 4 R 5 so the array would be 3 2 5 then I use sort function so it would be changed to 2 3 5 and then I go again with a foreach loop with a switch and if it is a 2 it would change whatever was in original array in that field to Q then E then R

Comment: I've tried sth like that with your method public function order_spells($champions){
  $order = array("Passive","Q","W","E","R");
  foreach(array_keys($champions) as $champion){
   
   $champions[$champion]=array_replace(array_flip($order), $champions[$champion]);
   
  }
  
  return $champions;
  
 }

It kinda works but it adds spells that didnt exist for that champion e.g. we have champion with Q W it will add empty passive E R to it as well

Comment: @Higeath If you don't know which one will be in the array and which not. Just add another `array_filter()` call around it to get the empty ones out, e.g. `$champions[$champion] = array_filter(array_replace(array_flip($order), $champions[$champion]));`

Comment: I've tried that here is var_dump of before sorting  http://i.imgur.com/kht0mza.png and after  http://i.imgur.com/XtC1jOV.png if you wouldn't mind taking a look

Comment: @Higeath Then we do a little trick. Just add this after your define `$order`: `$order= array_combine($order, array_fill(0, count($order), []));` With this We use your order as keys and fill the values with empty arrays, which then should get filtered out by `array_filter()`.

Comment: I think the problem is that $order is just a variable I created it isn't created by getting values from database i just created $order with Passive Q W E R values in it so I don't think there is much we could do I think I need a switch that would put values in $order variable in order and then just do array_replace and array_flip

Comment: @Higeath Have you tried my suggestion: `public function order_spells($champions){
  
  $order = array("Passive","Q","W","E","R");
  $order = array_combine($arr, array_fill(0, count($arr), []));
  
  foreach(array_keys($champions) as $champion){
   $champions[$champion] = array_replace($order, $champions[$champion]);
  }
  
  return $champions; 
   
 }` ?

Comment: what is $arr in this scenario? it was earlier array_pop but now it is not defined

Comment: @Higeath It's a copy&paste fail on my side :) Just change it from `$arr` -> `$order` in the 2 places where I missed it. (I will start a chat here, so we don't fill the comment section)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88499/discussion-between-rizier123-and-higeath).